# How to call onCreateView with 2 fragment in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments

So i have 2 fragments and i want the second fragment call onCreateView every time the user swipes on it. Also, as i can understand, FragmentPagerAdapter creates n+1 fragments and .setOffscreenPageLimit(0) will not work. setUserVisibleHint is also not quite what i want.

Answer (score 0):

Add your  onCreateView

```
PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter();
viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
pagerAdapter.setCurrentItem(1); //2 position fragment
```

Comment: You mean add this into my fragment? How is this gonna work?